# Amarok refuses to play *.ogg files

Tags: linux, debian, media, amarok

After recent upgrade to Amarok 2.1 it refuses to play *.ogg files. When I hit play, it blinks for a second and stops. No sound is generated. *.mp3 do play (although they stop after one song - see my other question). How can I fix it? It used to work with the old version (1.something).

EDIT: I checked that I can play *.ogg files in other Xine based players, e.g. gxine.

Comment: What distro?

Comment: Debian unstable, updated yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in Amarok Version 2.1.90 (its 2.2 rc1 I believe).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, under Ubuntu, albeit. You'll have to [install phonon-backend-xine](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180175). Once that was installed, it was all smooth sailing. Your other problem should also be fixed with this.

Comment: It was already installed.

Answer (score 1):

There's sometimes a problem with the Xine engine and Ogg files.  Can you play an Ogg file in Xine directly?  If you get an error like 'no demuxer plugin available' try exiting all audio playing applications, then open up a console and type in the following command:

```
rm .xine/catalog.cache
```

Then restart Amarok and see how it goes.

Comment: I had a similar problem and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, and I can play Ogg files in xine.